# Naming resources prior to creation using Neo4j Restful API

Tags: rest, neo4j

This is for people with knowledge on REST and Neo4j.
Is it possible to name a node before creating it in Neo4j ?
Typical Restful thing, you create a URI "XXX/db/data/node/mynode" and you want to create a node with this identifier if it is not existent in the moment.
For all that I have been researching (and testing) to the present moment, the answer is : "no it is not possible, neo4j will just always automatically give ids to the created nodes and the attempt to do create a URI and use POST to cause its creation will result in 405"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, you can't set the id of a node. What you can do is to add some other kind of id as a property, see [create node with properties](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-nodes.html#rest-api-create-node-with-properties). Just make sure it's [indexed automatically](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/auto-indexing.html) and then you can [query that index for exact matches](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-find-node-by-exact-match-from-an-automatic-index).

Comment: hmmm ... kinda sad, this does not seem much Restful, the proper thing would be to post to http://xxx:7474/node/xpto and have the xpto node created if not existent, then I would be able to work with standards and conventions instead of having to query the database to find by some hash based generated id ... anyway, it seems this is the only approach. Perhaps I need to open a new thread to ask this ... but What is the simplest way to query for the nodes for exact match ?